# Unable to start MongoDB on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I've just installed MongoDB on a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 installation, but I'm having trouble getting it to start (at all). I'm using the latest `mongo-stable` package via. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages.

I would expect it to start automatically on boot, however trying to start it manually always gives me the following:

```
$ sudo start mongodb
mongodb start/running, process 2565
$ sudo status mongodb
mongodb stop/waiting
```

`ps -aux` doesn't show anything mongo related. Trying to run the shell gives me:

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3
connecting to: test
Tue Oct 12 22:33:14 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 (anon):1137
exception: connect failed
```

both /var/log/mongodb and /var/lib/mongodb exist and were presumably created by the installer. Both are owned by the mongodb user (again setup by the installer), but both are empty, so there's no mongo log file for me to check, or .lock file for me to remove.

In case it's permissions related, both are

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb       mongodb       4096 2010-10-12 22:08 mongodb
```

There are no related log entries in /var/log/messages or syslog. I've tried reinstalling the package, just in case, but no difference. The version I'm running is listed as 20100930.

It's probably something simple, but I'm out of ideas, and with no errors or feedback whatsoever it's hard to know where the problem might lie. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't done so, create a data directory as described at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix

Check the contents of /etc/mongodb.conf

I would try running the mongodb executable directly and pass it command line options

- -v -v -v
- --logpath /tmp/mongotest

and anything else that seems useful from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters

Comment: The data directory had been created by the installer. When I ran the mongodb executable directly everything worked perfectly, which basically ruled out any issues with MongoDB. A bit of Googling later and I've fixed a problem with Upstart, and now Mongo is starting on boot. Many thanks.

Comment: Tim, would you mind sharing how you got Mongo to start during boot on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 13):

check if there's any mongo.lock file in /var/lib/mongo/ dir or your MONGOLIBDIR setting and remove it.

You should then be able to start the mongodb service.

Comment: +1 - Fixed it for me.

Comment: fixed for me too. could you elaborate on the problem that this fix is applied to?

Comment: deleting the mongod.lock worked for me

Comment: +1 - fixed my problem , just deleted mongod.lock file from /var/lib/mongodb/ directory